# How do I query a referenced object in MongoDB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, graphql

There are two collections in my mongo database: Book and Author

The Book collection has an author field which references the author who created it

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Author'  
})
```

I am using graphql, and my current code looks like this. booksByAuthor is a query that takes in a name, then returns the books written by that author.**(this is working and gives me the correct output)**

```
booksByAuthor: async (root) => {
  const author = await Author.findOne({name: root.name})
  
  return await Book.find({
    author: author._id
  })
}
```

My current implementation first queries the Author collection, and then uses the id of the author to then query the Book collection. However, I feel like there must be a way to do this without going through the Author collection.

Ideally, I want it to be something like this: (pseudo-code)

```
return await Book.find({
   author.name: {root.name}
```

})

I've tried doing

```
  return await Book.find({
    "author.name": { $in: [root.name] }
  })
```

and

```
  return await Book.find({
    name: { author: { $in: [root.name] } }
  })
```

but both returns an empty array. I don't know if I should even be using $in for this case

Comment: Plz add some sample documents from author and book collection so that we can write query.

Comment: Why do you think you can bypass going through `Author`?   If `Author` has a key and name e.g. `_id: ObjectId1, name: Buzz` and the query is by name, then you have to backmap to the `_id` to perform the lookup into the `Books` collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$lookup` to achieve this in single query. `$lookup` is similar to `joins` in sql.

Based on your question i have created some sample documents. Below is the query for getting the books by author.

```
db.book.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "author",
      "localField": "author",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "author"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "author.name": "Kafka"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sWt1uZE2eME). Please follow the link to see the query in action. You will also able to see the sample documents i have used. Feel free to play around with it according to your needs.